# Does a foreign key object have a unique id value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a job board site, where all jobs are displayed in a list and each one is a link that leads to a page displaying more information about the job.

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_employer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Employer.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_employer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.employer.save()

class Job(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(Employer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    establishment_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title + " - " + self.establishment_name \
               + ", " + self.poster.user.first_name + " " +self.poster.user.last_name
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'jobs' :jobs })
```

On index.html, the available jobs are listed as so:

```
 <table>
        <tbody>
             {% for job in jobs %}
                 <tr>
                     <td><a href="#">{{ job.job_title}} - {{ job.establishment_name }}</a></td>
                 </tr>
             {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want these to be clickable links, that will bring the user to another page giving them more details about the job. I am thinking that I need some kind of id value for `Job`objects to make this possible, but I may be wrong. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? Note: I have done something similar with user ids before:     `url(r'^claim/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClaimView.as_view(), name = "claim"),`, but how would I do this with `Job` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to clarify so you understand what's happening behind the scene.

***Id field is no magic***

In fact, Django is adding a field for you. Everytime you create a model Django add this field:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This assure uniqueness and data integrity troughout your database. Here is the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

For educational purposes here is a way you can override the default behavior:

```
my_field = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

**NOTE**

Also, people often don't think this is a big deal. But sometimes it really can be a life savior to really think about it. Because there is tons of questions on Stack asking how to revert this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

All models, including your Job model, have a unique primary key field, by default called `id`.

Comment: Welp, this was incredibly simple. Thanks Daniel!